# Blue Decoy shot by both Agent and Assassin

Tags: crossfire

I'm a Blue Decoy. At the end of the round, two guns are pointing at me - I get shot by an Agent first, then by an Assassin. Do I win? Does it count that an Assassin shot at me, even though I was already dead due to Agent shooting me first?

Comment: I don't own this game or have the rulebook in front of me but does being shot happen sequentially or is it supposed to be simultaneously in this game? That seems to be a major crux of the matter

Comment: First, all agents shoot simultaneously. Then all assassins do the same. Coming from that perspective we assumed that the answer to my question above is - no, I don't win. However, the exact wording of the rules might be relevant - the rules don't say "you win as Blue Decoy if *killed* by Assassin", but "you win as Blue Decoy if you get *shot* by Assassin". Strategically, it also makes sense that you should win - you performed your role's duty and pulled one Assassin's gun away from the VIP and onto yourself.

Comment: Seems to me that the latter is the answer because you were shot at by an assassin and there's no fail-criteria for being shot by an agent.